# Can I emulate DXGI_FORMAT_NV12 in Direct3D under Windows 7?

Tags: directx, direct3d, yuv, render-to-texture, dxgi

I need to convert an RGB texture to the NV12 format which the video codec understands (Y plane immediately followed by UV plane).  `DXGI_FORMAT_NV12` provides a straightforward view format mapping using R8 for Y and R8G8 for UV, so I use two pixel shaders with an NV12 texture.  Unfortunately, this only works on Windows 8.  Can I somehow create a texture that has both R8 and R8G8 shader resource views on Windows 7?  Or is there another way I can render the YUV data?

Answer (score 0):

create [CreateOffscreenPlainSurface()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174358(v=vs.85).aspx) with following D3DFORMAT

```
(D3DFORMAT)MAKEFOURCC('N', 'V', '1', '2') //842094158
```

more detail source code available at my git repo:

https://github.com/sailfish009/sample_direct3d_nv12

Comment: Thanks, but that's D3D9. The question is asking about D3D10.

Comment: @Timothy003 i hadn't tried D3D10, there is rare information about it. if you have to use shader, opengl is better alternative solution: https://github.com/sailfish009/sample_opengl_nv12